# asmx web services and key value parameters

Tags: .net, asmx

I currently have an asmx method defined like so :

```
[WebMethod]
public String Method1(Hashtable form)
```

It receives json objects with a variable number of attributes, for example :

```
{"form":{"name1":"10","name2":"20"}}
```

This is working fine and gives the expected results when called, but when I open the web service address in the browser, I get the error :

> The type System.Collections.Hashtable is not supported because it implements IDictionary

I've tried other data types, like `List<DictionaryEntry>` which will fix this, but then be empty when the method is called, and I can't find something that will work in both cases...

What is the "correct" way of doing this?

Comment: How is this working with `Hashtable` if you are getting an exception?

Comment: Calling the method from client script works fine, the only problem is opening the base .asmx.

Answer (score 1):

`IDictionary` cannot be serialized to XML (which is how asmx web services work), so you cannot use any implementation of `IDictionary` either as a return value or as a parameter.

So the "correct" way of doing this is to use anything that doesn't implement `IDictionary`.  You could do something like this instead:

```
[WebMethod]
public String Method1(params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] formdata)
```

and then call it like this:

```
service.Method1(new KeyValuePair("name1", "10"), new KeyValuePair("name2", "20"));
```

Comment: I tried this method definition, but I get a "No parameterless constructor defined for the type of KeyValuePair<String, String>[]" error. I should also mention that I don't have control over the incoming json data.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I can do this as a workaround :

```
[WebMethod]
public String Method1(Object form)
{
    Dictionary<String, Object> data = (Dictionary<String, Object>)form;
```

And the service .asmx page loads without error.

This still makes no sense to me though...

Comment: I can't see how that would work... Is data fully populated or is it null?